# Updating column conditional on other columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My server was crashed, damaging my database. In one of my tables I have an `academic_quality` column where I store school grades like `A, B, C+, D`. Somehow, my grades are not distributed through other columns on some rows. I thought I could create a conditional clause and create a new column, `academic_quality_new`, and update it after checking other columns. I tried the following query but it did not work.

```
SELECT  academic_quality, acceptance_rate, undergrads, setting, environment, degrees_offered,
        CASE WHEN (academic_quality OR acceptance_rate OR undergrads OR setting OR environment OR degrees_offered) = 'A' THEN INSERT 'A' INTO academic_quality_new 
        CASE WHEN (academic_quality OR acceptance_rate OR undergrads OR setting OR environment OR degrees_offered) = 'C' THEN INSERT 'B' INTO academic_quality_new         
FROM [school_List_V4]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Do you want to select a computed column, or do an update?  Also, if the latter note that you have no `WHERE` clause.  _Which_ records should be targeted for update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by adding case..when for all available grades.

First you can execute select query and check result

```
select * ,
case when academic_quality = 'A' OR acceptance_rate = 'A' then  'A'
else case when academic_quality ='B' OR acceptance_rate = 'B' then  'B'
     else case when  academic_quality = 'C' OR acceptance_rate =  'C' then  'C'
        else '--'
        end
     end
end
from table1
```

then try this update query, it will update new column. If 2 cases are true then it will take first case, so case on grades should be from highest to lowest.

```
update table1
set new =
case when academic_quality = 'A' OR acceptance_rate = 'A' then  'A'
else case when academic_quality ='B' OR acceptance_rate = 'B' then  'B'
     else case when  academic_quality = 'C' OR acceptance_rate =  'C' then  'C'
        else '--'
        end
     end
end
```

and final updated new column is select * from table1

```
academic_quality | acceptance_rate | new
A                | NULL            | A         
NULL             | B               | B         
NULL             | NULL            | --        
A                | B               | A         
C                | B               | B
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve.